# javascript getting url using location.search not working

Tags: javascript

I am using chrome 28.0.1500.95 m version, when i use javascript code

> window.location.search or  location.search or  window.location.hash

it is returns null but in javascript doc its given it will return url. Can any one help me out of this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `location.href`. Also show your code..

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for fetching the URL then

```
window.location.href;
```

Answer (score 0):

The location object under the window object contains several pieces of info. [Check out some docs here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location)